# Class attribute inside header <h1>tags?

Tags: html

I read somewhere that you should try to avoid using class or any styles inside Header tags

```
<h1 class="story">Here goes the story</h1>
```

Is there any problem if we apply css class inside header tags?

Comment: Can u please give the link where u read it ?. Because i dont think so.

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Comment: Sure, here is the link where it says to avoid using class inside H1 (or header tags) - http://www.perfect-optimization.com/blog/seo-id-44f784384295d.html

Comment: Instead of using a class, i think we have to specify header as H1{ } H2{ } inside CSS and not like H1.boldtext{ } :)

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using css class styles inside of header tags. CSS is meant to style your content. Aside from making changes easier, that is rather than changing twenty files you simply change the css file, the idea is to keep content separate from appearance. Not only is this standard compliant, it improves usability, decreases bandwidth usage, and helps index your pages better in search engines.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why that would be a problem.  There isn't any problem to speak of.

Only thing you want to keep in mind is a clear separation of concerns.  If you start adding class attributes like so:

```
<h1 class="blue">I'm blue text!</h1>
<h6 class="small">I'm small text!</h6>
```

`blue` and `small` show styling seeping into your markup.  This is both verbose and unnecessary.  This of course applies to all HTML elements, not just headers.

Comment: I dont und whats wrong with the above styling that you have provided..can u please clarify this.? verbose and unnecessary why?

Comment: The problem is that you're letting the presentation overstep into your semantics.  Class and id HTML attributes should be reserved for content-pertinent descriptors.  Thus any class or id attribute that is describing the style of the element should be avoided.  This is not mandatory however, but is widely-adopted for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with styling `h1`. CSS is just a decorator for the DOM so you should use it. This has a lot of different meanings. For example you can have 100 `h1` tags but 10 of them are in red, 50 of them have Arial font and so forth. This is why it was implemented CSS, even if it is still a lousy solution, it is the best we have. Even if it is not correct from the SEO perspective to have 100 `h1` tags in a page, there is no problem in styling it. Basically because the concept of visual identity of a page has a lot to do with the human perception, not only the crawler's opinion.

**Therefor the answer is:** Go ahead and style any tag you want, the optimization for SEO and the Web-Site itself stands elsewhere.